# Assign a counter in SQL Server to records with sequential dates, and only increment when dates not sequential

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to assign a `Trip #` to records for Customers with sequential days, and increment the Trip ID if they have a break in sequential days, and come later in the month for example.  The data structure looks like this:

```
CustomerID    Date
1             2014-01-01
1             2014-01-02
1             2014-01-04
2             2014-01-01
2             2014-01-05
2             2014-01-06
2             2014-01-08
```

The desired output based upon the above example dataset would be:

```
CustomerID    Date          Trip
1             2014-01-01    1
1             2014-01-02    1
1             2014-01-04    2
2             2014-01-01    1
2             2014-01-05    2
2             2014-01-06    2
2             2014-01-08    3
```

So if the Dates for that Customer are back-to-back, it is considered the same Trip, and has the same Trip #.  Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?  I am using MSSQL 2012.

My initial thoughts are to use the `LAG`, `ROW_NUMBER`, or `OVER/PARTITION BY` function, or even a `Recursive Table Variable Function`.  I can paste some code, but in all honesty, my code isn't working so far.  If this is a simple query, but I am just not thinking about it correctly, that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: since you have mentioned LAG() function is it SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: @M.Ali, yes, I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Which data type is `Date`? A `DATE` or `DATETIME` or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it is type `Date`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Date` is a `DATE` (ie has no hours), you could for example use `DENSE_RANK()` by `Date - ROW_NUMBER() days` which will give a constant value for continuous days, something like;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CustomerID, Date, 
    DATEADD(DAY, 
            -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Date), 
            Date) dt
  FROM trips
)
SELECT CustomerID, Date, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY dt)
FROM cte;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfe56/1).